# Sum Data Across Individual Rows in a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to create a rule where as long as the sum of all data across each individual row in the dataframe is greater than one, the `response` will equal to one. Please see below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df1['Response'] = 0

df1
Out[14]: 
   A  B  C  D  Response
0  0  0  0  0         0
1  0  1  1  0         0
2  1  1  1  1         0
3  0  0  0  0         0
4  0  1  1  1         0
5  1  1  0  0         0
6  1  1  0  0         0
7  0  1  1  1         0
8  0  0  0  0         0
9  0  1  1  1         0
```

My attempt:

```
df1['Response'] = 1 if [sum(df1[i,:]) for i in range(10)] > 1 else 0
```

However I get this error, instead of having three rows equal to zero and the remaining equal to 1 in the `response` column:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `df1['Response'] = df1.sum(1).gt(1).astype(int)`

Comment: Will all of your numbers be positive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with `clip_upper` : set a upper boundary .

```
df.sum(1).clip_upper(1)
Out[153]: 
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    0
4    1
5    1
6    1
7    1
8    0
9    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (it assumes all of the numbers are positive):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...: import pandas as pd
   ...: df1 = pd.read_clipboard()

In [2]: df1
Out[2]:
   A  B  C  D  Response
0  0  0  0  0         0
1  0  1  1  0         0
2  1  1  1  1         0
3  0  0  0  0         0
4  0  1  1  1         0
5  1  1  0  0         0
6  1  1  0  0         0
7  0  1  1  1         0
8  0  0  0  0         0
9  0  1  1  1         0

In [3]: df1['Response'] = df1.any(1).astype(int)

In [4]: df1
Out[4]:
   A  B  C  D  Response
0  0  0  0  0         0
1  0  1  1  0         1
2  1  1  1  1         1
3  0  0  0  0         0
4  0  1  1  1         1
5  1  1  0  0         1
6  1  1  0  0         1
7  0  1  1  1         1
8  0  0  0  0         0
9  0  1  1  1         1
```